# MySQL IF THEN Query won't work

Tags: mysql, if-statement

have a problem with a MySQL query:

```
IF (SELECT group_concat(SN) FROM AG as del WHERE (SN='12345678' AND del.AS_Status<>'E')) IS NULL THEN

*do something e.g.* select * from ag;

END IF;
```

I want just to check if for every colum the status is E. 
If I just use the query:

```
SELECT group_concat(SN) FROM AG as del WHERE (SN='12345678' AND del.AS_Status<>'E') ;
```

no problem at all.

any ideas?

Thanks,
Sascha

Comment: The `if` statement is only allowed in functional blocks of code, such as stored procedures, functions, and triggers.

Comment: Thanks, I just took it out of the procedure for troubleshooting didn't bear in mind this could cause a problem.